# how convert values string into a integer object array by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, converters

i have this object array:

```js
let arr = [
    {
        'pippo': '1',
    'descrizione': 'ciao'
    }
];
```

and i want convert "1" to 1 by key:

```js
let arr = [
        {
            'pippo': 1,
        'descrizione': 'ciao'
        }
    ];
```

any solution?

br
Max

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the objects and create a new array with the converted number with the help of [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```
arr = arr.map(item => { 
   return {
      ...item, //copies all items first...
      pippo: parseInt(item.pippo) //...then overwrites pippo
   }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to make the function generic? I try to explain myself better.. it's possible use: if(key === 'pippo') => key: parseINt(item[key]) ??